# Just getting nothing from my form submission page (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

i'm pretty new to web development but I'm currently playing with an idea I have, and I wanted to make a page that allowed logged in users to report a problem and it get send to whatever e-mail was in the e-mail field for that user. The problem is, when I click the submit button I just get taken to a white page, and it doesn't appear that any of the php is working, however. I did an include_once on my page top and page bottom for my pages and they showed up, so It would seem the PHP is getting run, but I'm getting nothing back. Could someone have a look at this and suggest why it might not be working?

Thanks.

This is the page with my form on, and it would appear that everything is working on here.

```
<?php
include_once("php_includes/problem_form_email.php"); ?>

  <form action="problem_form_email.php" method="post" name="reportform" id="reportform">
    <div>Full Name: </div>
    <input id="fullname" type="text" maxlength="64">
    <div>Your Email address:</div>
    <input id="tenantemail" type="text" maxlength="88">
    <div>Your Phone number:</div>
    <input id="phonenumber" type="text" maxlength="64">
    <div>House Number or Name:</div>
    <input id="housenumber" type="text" maxlength="64">
    <div>First Line of address:</div>
    <input id="streetname" type="text" maxlength="64">
    <div>City:</div>
    <input id="city" type="text" maxlength="64">
    <div>Your Postcode:</div>
    <input id="postcode" type="text" maxlength="14">
    <div>Type of Problem:</div>
    <select id="typeofproblem">
    <option value="">TYPE OF PROBLEM</option>
<option value="Water">Water</option>
<option value="Decor">Decor(Paintwork, wallpaper etc.)</option>
<option value="Heating">Heating</option>
<option value="Windows">Windows</option>
<option value="Flooring">Flooring</option>
<option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
<option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
<option value="Roofing">Roofing</option>
    </select>
    <div>Describe your problem (Please be detailed):</div>
    <TEXTAREA style="resize:none; width:300px;" name="probdesc" ROWS=8 COLS=64 onfocus="emptyElement('status')"></textarea>
    <div>How urgent is this problem?:<br> Urgency is to help us filter the most in need cases, please don't abuse it.</div>
    <select id="urgency" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
<option value="Very Low">Very Low</option>
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Very High">Very High</option>
    </select>

    <div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <input type='submit' value="Report Problem">
  </form>
```

All the variables should then go to my other page, which will send an e-mail the the user and then display some sort of success HTML. This is where I think i've done something wrong. Take a look...

I used a template form submission page and changed it, the template form can be found here.
http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

I would just like to clarify that the HTML part of this php page doesn't get shown at al

```
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id='$log_id' AND username='$log_username'LIMIT 1";

$email_to = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
echo "$email_to";
 $email_subject = "MOUSE ACCOUNT - A Tenant has reported a problem";


    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['fullname']) ||

        !isset($_POST['tenantemail']) ||

        !isset($_POST['phonenumber']) ||

        !isset($_POST['housenumber']) ||

        !isset($_POST['streetname']) ||

        !isset($_POST['city']) ||

        !isset($_POST['postcode']) ||

        !isset($_POST['typeofproblem']) ||

        !isset($_POST['probdesc']) ||

        !isset($_POST['urgency'] )) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      

    }

$fullname = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9."@; ]#i', '', $_POST['fullname']);
$tenantemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['tenantemail']);
$phonenumber = preg_replace('#[0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['phonenumber']);
$housenumber = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['housenumber']);
$streetname = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]', '', $_POST['streetname']);
$city = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]', '', $_POST['city']);
$postcode = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]', '', $_POST['postcode']);
$typeofproblem = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]', '', $_POST['typeofproblem']);
$probdesc = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9."@; ]', '', $_POST['probdesc']);
$urgency = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['urgency']);


    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$tenantemail)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$fullname)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$phonenumber)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($probdesc) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }

$email_from = "maintenance@mouseaccount.com";
$email_message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Maintenance Request</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.mouseaccount.com"><img src="http://www.mouseaccount.com/images/logo.png" width="36" height="30" alt="Mouse Account" style="border:none; float:left;"></a>A tenant reported a problem!</div><div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello,<br /><br />A tenant has reported a problem at their property, please view below to see the details of the report so you can contact them.
<br /><br />Name: <b>'.$fullname.'</b><br /><br />
<br /><br />Tenants Contact Email: <b>'.$tenantemail.'</b><br /><br />
<br /><br />Tenants Phone Number: <b>'.$phonenumber.'</b><br /><br />
<br /><br />House Number: <b>'.$housenumber.'</b><br /><br />
<br /><br />Street Name: <b>'.$streetname.'</b><br /><br />
<br /><br />City: <b>'.$city.'</b><br /><br />
<br /><br />Postcode: <b>'.$postcode.'</b><br /><br />
<br /><br />Category of Problem: <b>'.$typeofproblem.'</b><br /><br />
<br /><br />Description of their problem <br /><br />:'.$probdesc.'<br /><br />
<br /><br />Urgency Indicated by tenant: <b>'.$urgency.'</b><br /><br />

Tenants Contact Email:<br />* E-mail Address: <b>'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
$headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "signup_success";
exit();





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

?>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Mouse Account</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <script src="root/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php include_once("template_pageTop.php");?>
<div id="maincontent">

<div id="pageMiddle">&nbsp;
    <div id="img1"><img src="images/welcome_toMA.png" id="img1"></img></div></div></div>
<?php include_once("template_pageBottom.php");?>

</body>
</html>



<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: I can't really trim down the last php page because I don't have a clue what might be causing it to not execute.

Comment: are you understanding the code ? if you're a beginner then i'll say start from begin not from others code.

Comment: I do understand the code, yes. I just understand where I could go wrong.

Comment: where are `$log_id` and `$log_username` being populated?

Comment: That's what @yuvi told you. trim the code. So one can read easily. It is taking lot of time to read the whole code.

Comment: @Class $log_id and $log_username is populated in my checkuserlogin.php file which checks to see if the user is logged in, I've tested this and it does work.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have a lot inputs without any `name` parameters which PHP uses to populate `$_GET`/`$_POST`

```
<input id="fullname" type="text" maxlength="64">
```

which should look like:

```
<input id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text" maxlength="64">
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Theres might be more errors in your script but adding this should help you some

Also you mentioned that `$log_id` and `$log_username` are being populated but where is`checkuserlogin.php` being called? is it being called in `db_conx.php` otherwise theres your problem. You might want to turn on error messages to receive messages.

Comment: I added in the name part but still nothing.

Comment: $user_ok is what is being used in checkuserlogin.php. It is only used for that very first if statement. It is not called in db_conx.php db conx is only used to connect to the database.

Comment: Also just realised I have no need for db_conx.php in this file because it is called in checkuserlogin.php Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add name parameters like Class said and also change

```
<input type='submit' value="Report Problem">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Report Problem">
```

Also remove

```
include_once("php_includes/problem_form_email.php");
```

You dont need this, otherwise you are not closing php tag

```
<?php
include_once("php_includes/problem_form_email.php");
```

Change it to

```
<?php
include_once("php_includes/problem_form_email.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Added that, still getting the problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: remove include_once("php_includes/problem_form_email.php"); that is causing error I believe

Comment: main problem is that you are not closing php tag and it is considering all in PHP code

Comment: using `"` or `'` can be done interchangeably as long as you are matching up alike with alike but just keep consistent with what you feel is best

Comment: I know just a random workaround on server running old php versions but he is not closing php tag

Comment: @Hamza that was just a problem with my edit, It is actually In there and working. I also removed the include_once and it didn't change anything. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You need to remove that, rest code is fine and working at my end, You need to verify your all code whether you are closing every tag or not

Comment: Just curious, how do you know it's working at your end? I've cut out bits of the php that you don't need, so I don't know how it could be working.

Comment: Yeah this is what I am saying this part is working, so include all of your code in the question and let me know. Html part is not shown only when tags are not correct

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've got it to show up one thing, the problem was I wasn't including checkuserlogin.php in my problem_form_email.php and so my sql statement couldn't execute. But now I just keep getting them errors that show up below. and I have no way to make them stop, any additional help?